# Minimum number of steps required to make all elements of sequence 0

Tags: algorithm, greedy

Given a sequence of integers calculate the minimum number of operations required to make all numbers 0. An operation is of the following:
Increase or decrease all numbers from index i to index j by 1.

Example 1)

{1, 1, -1}

You can do:

Decrease indices 0 to 1

Increase indices 2 to 2

So the answer is 2 operations.

Example 2)

{3, -1, -1, 3}

Decrease indices 0 to 3

Decrease indices 0 to 3

Decrease indices 0 to 3

Increase indices 1 to 2

Increase indices 1 to 2

Increase indices 1 to 2

Increase indices 1 to 2

So answer is 7.

What would be an efficient algorithm to do this?

Comment: It's equivalent to find the number of sequences in which all numbers have the same sign. so first and last indices in each sequence indicate `i` and `j`, respectively.

Comment: @agtabesh what if the numbers aren't all just 1 or -1. For example {3, 1, 1, 3}. They all have the same sign but the answer is 5.

Comment: Where does this problem come from? Do you have a link? Besides, il would be better if you show us your attempt.

Comment: Spit-balling ideas: I’m thinking you need to find something a “line of best fit” (call it X): a number which has the lowest average distance to all other numbers. The first part of my algorithm is to move numbers up/down to get them all to have that value. The second part is to just move the entire set of numbers up/down from X, to 0. Notice the first part is a repeat of the sub problem: for internals of numbers (idk how to pick these, yet), you can find a “local line of best fit”, call it X2. You then move all those numbers from X2 to X

Comment: Problem statement says "positive integers" but the example has `-1`.

Comment: The second example can be solved with decrease [0,0] three times, decrease [3,3] three times, and increase [1,2] one time, for a total of 7 operations. So the first question I would ask myself is, "Is it ever advantageous to move a number away from 0?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is that there are many ways to get final result to 0, even with the minimum number of operations in all cases.

For example, with `{1, 0, 1}`, we an apply `-1` on `[0, 2]` and `+1` on `[1, 1]`
or we can apply `-1` on `[0, 0]`, and then `-1`on `[2, 2]`.

In both cases, two operations are needed.

As only the minimum number of operations is needed, we can decide to split the operations on distinct intervals as soon as it seems not suboptimal.

Then, an iterative procedure is applied, by comparing the values between adjacent indices.

For example, if the signs are different, or if the new value is `0`, we can decide to split the intervals.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int count_operations (const std::vector<int> &A) {
    int n = A.size();
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    int count = std::abs (A[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        if (A[i]*A[i-1] > 0) {
            if(std::abs(A[i]) > std::abs(A[i-1])) {
                count += std::abs(A[i]) - std::abs(A[i-1]);
            }
        } else {
            count += std::abs(A[i]);
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> A = {1 , 1, -1};
    auto ans = count_operations (A);
    std::cout << ans << "\n";
    
    A = {3, -1, -1, 3};
    ans = count_operations (A);
    std::cout << ans << "\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```